# Maximum likelihood estimation of p from a Binomial sample count

Tags: maximum-likelihood, binomial-distribution

There is already an answer here on the ML estimator for binomial p: [Maximum likelihood estimation of p in a Binomial sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149202/maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-p-in-a-binomial-sample)

Let me add a twist to the question: let's assume we don't know all the samples, but only count for a single value. So, for example, we have drawn M samples from a binomial distribution with known parameter N and unknown parameter p. The only information we know is that out of these M samples, m of them are equal to some value k.

So my question is: what is the ML estimator for p in Bin(N,p) if we know that m out of M samples are equal to k?

Comment: Just for clarity: the problem is that you (for concreteness) have two coins (A and B) with different probabilities of generating a head, and you don't know how many flips come from each coin.  Your objective is to estimate the probability of generating a head from coin A?  Does that seem about right?

Comment: This question definitely needs more clarity!  Could you provide a more specific description of your model?  What exactly is the relationship between the "1000" and "500 samples" you stipulate at the end?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I edited the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can readily reduce this to a simpler problem.  Since the chance that a Binomial$(N,p)$ observation equals $k$ is given by $q=\binom{N}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$, you have data that are equivalent to flipping a coin $M$ times, observing it came up heads $m$ times, and wish to estimate the chance $q$ of heads.  From $q$ you can compute $p$.

Comment: Great idea! Can you offer it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> Since the chance that a Binomial$(N,p)$ observation equals $k$ is
> given by $q=\binom{N}{k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$, you have data that are
> equivalent to flipping a coin $M$ times, observing it came up heads
> $m$ times, and wish to estimate the chance $q$ of heads.  From $q$ you
> can compute $p$.

- whuber

Comment: I was hoping to credit the author