# Calculating probability curve of a binomial sample

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

Apologies, I'm not a stats-person, I'm looking for a concept that I'm struggling to Google.

I have a boolean function that returns true or false at some unknown chance c. I have a sample of 100 function-executions, 70% of which returned True.

I'm looking to graph, for every value 0-1 the odds that the function actually had c=value.

What stats concept am I looking for?

Apologies again for my lack of stats here.

Comment: You are presumably looking for the [likelihood function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) for the probability parameter given that observation (*likelihood* is neither *probability* nor *odds*)

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149202/maximum-likelihood-estimation-of-p-in-a-binomial-sample

Comment: Thanks y'all 