# Which is the likelihood function of the logit model?

Tags: logistic, likelihood

I'm wondering which is the likelihood function for a logit model and how I can derive it. Thanks!

Comment: What are you looking for beyond “binomial”?

Comment: Some possible duplicates: Do they help?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181035/how-to-derive-the-likelihood-function-for-binomial-distribution-for-parameter-es,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384296/deriving-likelihood-function-of-binomial-distribution-confusion-over-exponents,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505312/what-is-the-likelihood-function-and-mle-of-binomial-distribution