# Logistic regression with proportion data (interpretation of the log-odds-ratios, family binomial or quasibinomial, include random intercepts?)

Tags: r, regression, logistic, binomial-distribution

I found this discussion very helpful for the analysis I need to conduct for my thesis:
[In using the cbind() function in R for a logistic regression on a $2 \times 2$ table, what is the explicit functional form of the regression equation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/259502/in-using-the-cbind-function-in-r-for-a-logistic-regression-on-a-2-times-2-t/615666#615666)

**I am not sure if I understand it right, that the multiple trials that are mentioned in the discussion are done within the same sample? (but I think so)**
In my case I have a control and a treatment group, and each respondent goes through 4 questions where he/she has to choose between train and plane. I now want to analyse the difference between control and treatment group over all four choices combined. So I think I could use the approach with a weighted logistic regression model and the dependent variable "proportion_train" (which represents how often the train was chosen out of the four choices).

I am also not sure about the interpretation of the coefficients of this model then. I know these are most likely the log-odds-ratios (or equivalently differences in log-odds). But **do these log-odds-ratios show the probability combined over all trials (which I want to find out), or the per-trial probability?**

Also, in some other forum someone used "family=quasibinomial" for a logistic regression model with proportion data. How do I find out if for my data I have to use "family=binomial" or "family=quasibinomial"? Or **can you in general say that for a weighted logistic regression model with proportion data as dependent variable, the family is binomial?**

I also read somewhere else that one **needs to account for the correlation within the individuals by including random intercepts for the individual IDs** (I guess as e. g. in my case the four questions were answered by the same individuals (but different individuals in control and treatment group of course).
In the discussion I mentioned above, no one included such a random intercept for the individuals in the weighted logistic regression model (with proportion data as dependent variable), so I am **wondering if it's necessary or not?**

Thanks for your support!