# Correct way to speak and write about likelihoods

Tags: terminology, likelihood

We define likelihood of parameters $\theta$ given observations $x$ (assuming $x$ is sampled according to density $f$) as:
$$\mathcal{L}(\theta | x)=f_\theta(x).
$$
**Is it correct to speak about "[l]ikelihood of the data"** (The Elements of Statistical Learning before equation (2.35)), or should we only speak about the likelihood of parameters?

I also get such remark during oral presentation, but I'm still confused to know if this misnomer is accepted.

---

In addition, the first equation comes from the English Wikipedia, but in the French ones it is written:
$$\mathcal{L}(x | \theta)=f(x;\theta).$$
I think this notation $\mathcal{L}(x | \theta)$ is incorrect, but is it accepted somehow? 
Are there some authoritative notation rules for likelihood, or each author picks as he wants?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "authoritative sources", but I would say the notation from French Wikipedia is strange, and I have never seen it. Also, I wold replace the one you attribute to English Wikipedia with
$$
   \mathcal{L}(\theta | x)\propto f_\theta(x).
$$ (where we assume the constant of proportionality is positive.)  For proportionality see [What does "likelihood is only defined up to a multiplicative constant of proportionality" mean in practice?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97515/what-does-likelihood-is-only-defined-up-to-a-multiplicative-constant-of-proport/97522#97522).

So likelihood is a measure of support for a model, and as long as we look at a parameterized family of models, that will be a function of the parameters. So say **likelihood for the parameter $\theta$ given the data $x$**.  Likelihood for the data doesn't give much meaning for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't speak of likelihood of the data. Of the four possible ways to mix likelihood/probability and data/parameters, you speak of:

either

- likelihood of the parameters (given the data)

or

- probability or probability density of the data (given the parameters)

In a Bayesian probability setting, where the parameters *also* follow a probability distribution, you may speak as well of (posterior/prior) probability of parameters.

---

The difference depends on which part of the equation is considered fixed.

Likelihood is considered **a function of the parameters (ie theta)** given a particular observation $x$ $$\mathcal{L}(\theta|x)$$ The vertical bar $|$ is used to say that $x$ is a fixed parameter and $\theta$ is variable (but of course, you can encounter different $x$ and it is only fixed for the particular case).

The likelihood relates to [inverse probability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_probability), which contrasts with the typical concept of probability that gives:

- The probability of observations *given* some set of parameters.

This typical concept of probability is often a straightforward problem. The problem of inverse probability is to express:

- The probability  (or something related) of the set of parameters *given* some observation.

Which is not straightforward, or even an impossible (ill-defined) problem.