# Is likelihood function always unique?

Tags: probability, estimation, inference, likelihood

I am reading the following part of a book. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
What I do not understand in Sample 3 is that why $F_M(m)$ is not the likelihood function. As in sample 2, we produced the probability that $0.9< X < 4$. Similarly, $F_M(m)$ (can be expressed as $F_M(m,\theta)$ can provide the probability of $X_i\le3.5,i = 1,...,5$ for $m = 3.5.$

In other words, if I consider all the individual samples independent from each other, I can get likelihood of each sample as follows:
$G_i(\theta) = \Phi(3.5-\theta)$ as $-\infty\le X_i\le 3.5$
After this, I can extract the likelihood as follows:
$L_3(\theta) = \prod\limits_{i = 1}^5 {{G_i(\theta)}} = (\Phi(3.5-\theta))^5$.

What do I miss? Why is my result different than the book?
Should the likelihood $L_3(\theta)$ be unique or my likelihood in above equation is also correct?

Comment: See  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97515/what-does-likelihood-is-only-defined-up-to-a-multiplicative-constant-of-proport/97522#97522

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thanks. You pointed out a very very interesting example. Moreover, do you think that the likelihood function I made and the one in the book are both correct? Thanks a ton!

Comment: The one in the book is correct. If yours is different it is wrong

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for this book excerpt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is likelihood function always unique?**

The likelihood function is as unique as the probability distribution function. Different variables may have different distribution functions, but there is only one distribution function for each variable.

---

> **why $F_M(m)$ is not the likelihood function**

$F_M(m)$ is the *cumulative* distribution/density function (CDF).

$$\begin{array}\\
F_M(m) &=& \int_{-\infty}^{m} f(t) \text{d}t\\ &=& Pr(M \leq m)
\end{array}$$

The likelihood function is related to the probability density distribution (PDF), not to the *cumulative* density/distribution function.

$$\mathcal{L}(\theta \vert m) = f_M(m \vert \theta) \neq F_M(m \vert \theta)$$

> **As in sample 2, we produced the probability that $0.9< X < 4$. Similarly, $F_M(m)$ (can be expressed as $F_M(m,\theta)$ can provide the probability of $X_i\le3.5,i = 1,...,5$ for $m = 3.5.$**

The event that $M=m$ does not equal the event that each of the five $X_i\leq m$. (so you are coming up with the likelihood function for a different observation set)

The difference is that at least one of the five inequalities $X_i\leq m$ must be an equality.

$M=m$ implies $X_i\leq m$, but the other way around is not true.

So you get  $5\phi(m-\theta)\Phi(m-\theta)^4$ instead of $\Phi(m-\theta)^5$.

The term $5\phi(m-\theta)$ refers to the equality relation, and the second part $\Phi(m-\theta)^4$ relates to the inequality relations.

Comment: I completely understood your explanation; however, we can also have 2 observations equal to 3.5 giving rise to $5\phi(m-\theta)^2$ as the equality relation and $\Phi(m-\theta)^3$ as equality relation. In fact, in this case our likelihood should be as follows:  

$L_3(\theta) = \Phi(m-\theta)^4\phi(m-\theta) + \Phi(m-\theta)^3\phi(m-\theta)^2 + \Phi(m-\theta)^2\phi(m-\theta)^3 + \Phi(m-\theta)^1\phi(m-\theta)^4 + \phi(m-\theta)^5$

This is because the maximum of all 5 observations = 3.5 does not mean that only one observation is equal to 3.5.

Comment: @AmmarAhmed you only need one of the five terms being an equality (which indeed you can do in five ways). The situation $X_i=m$ for one of the $i$ and $X_i \leq m$ for the other four covers everything (since there are five different $i$ that you can set equal you get this factor 5). Note that for the other four it says less than *or equal*, so you can have more than only one observation equal to 3.5.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{c}
((X_1=m) \wedge (X_2 \leq m) \wedge (X_3 \leq m) \wedge (X_4 \leq m) \wedge (X_5\leq m)) \\
\lor\\
((X_1 \leq m) \wedge (X_2 = m) \wedge (X_3 \leq m) \wedge (X_4 \leq m) \wedge (X_5\leq m)) \\
\lor\\
((X_1 \leq m) \wedge (X_2 \leq m) \wedge (X_3 = m) \wedge (X_4 \leq m) \wedge (X_5\leq m)) \\
\lor\\
((X_1 \leq m) \wedge (X_2 \leq m) \wedge (X_3 \leq m) \wedge (X_4 = m) \wedge (X_5\leq m)) \\
\lor\\
((X_1 \leq m) \wedge (X_2 \leq m) \wedge (X_3 \leq m) \wedge (X_4 \leq m) \wedge (X_5 = m)) \\
\Leftrightarrow \\
M = m
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood is unique for each of the three experiments, the difference is between the three experiments in that one gets three different summaries of the 5 Normal random variables:

1. $x^\text{obs}=x_1=2.3$
2. $x^\text{obs}=\mathbb{I}_{(.9,4)}(x_1)=1$
3. $x^\text{obs}=\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_5\}=3.5$

The three summaries have different distributions hence the likelihood differs across the three cases.

In the last one, observing that $$X_{(5)}\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\max\{x_1,\ldots,x_5\}=3.5$$which has density$$5\mathbb{P}_\theta(X_1\le 3.5)^4f_\theta(3.5)$$ is not equivalent to observing that all five Normal realisations are less than $3.5$, which has probability$$\mathbb{P}_\theta(X_1\le 3.5)^5$$ since in the former setting *one* of these realisations took the value $3.5$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the likelihood will be unique for the three cases as they have different observation set. My question is: Is it possible to get two likelihood functions for Sample 3. I understand that the ${\text{max}} \{x_1, x_2,...,x_5\} = 3.5$ which means at least one of the observation in Sample 3 is equal to $3.5$. But the authors also exploited the independence assumption between the 5 Normal realizations while calculating the second and third step of $F_M(m)$.

Comment: No, there is a single likelihood function in Case #3.