# Deriving likelihood function $\prod_{i=1}^n p^{x_i} (1-p)^{1-x_i}$ from $n$ independent Bernoulli experiments

Tags: binomial-distribution, likelihood, bernoulli-distribution

I am studying [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/97522/163242), by user kjetil b halvorsen, on likelihood functions. He says the following:

> We model $n$ independent Bernoulli experiments, leading to data $X_1, \dots, X_n$, each with a Bernoulli distribution with (probability) parameter $p$. This leads to the likelihood function
>   $$
>    \prod_{i=1}^n p^{x_i} (1-p)^{1-x_i}
> $$

How does one come to the conclusion that the likelihood function is

$$
   \prod_{i=1}^n p^{x_i} (1-p)^{1-x_i}?
$$

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this.

Comment: The definition of a likelihood function (of a parameter) is the probability function of the sample where the random variable $X$ is set to the observed value $x$. For *independent* random variables, their *joint* probability is the product of their marginal pmfs. For a Bernoulli RV, the pmf is $p^X(1-p)^{1-X}$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @AdamO Thank you. Almost. I'm still unclear on the connection between the likelihood function and the joint probability; I think that is where my confusion lies.

Comment: Likelihood Function in this case: $$P(X_1,\dots,X_n|p)=\prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i|p)$$

Comment: @gunes Ahh, that makes sense. How does that definition relate to the definitions provided here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Definition ? I checked the Wikipedia page before posting this question, but I wasn't able to see the connection (which was the impetus for posting this question).

Comment: $P_\theta(X=x)$ means the same thing as $P(X=x|\theta)$. Sometimes, $\theta$ is just an unknown parameter, sometimes it's modeled as a RV in which the given notation makes more sense.

Comment: @gunes Ok, I understand now. Thank you both for taking the time to clarify this.